# HTML Span of table cells that belong to a class

Tags: html, pug

I have a small example where I want to hide/show radio buttons depending on the users choice. However, the colspan attribute is not functioning properly for some reason.

```
  style.
    .hide {
      display: none;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  body
    table(align='center', 8px='', cellpadding="10", border=1)
      tr
        th
          input(type='radio', name='tab', value='red', onclick='red();')
          | Red
        th
          input(type='radio', name='tab', value='blue', onclick='blue();')
          | Blue
      tr
        td#color.hide(colspan='2')
           input(type='radio', value='light', name='one')
           | light red
           input(type='radio', value='dark', name='two')
           | dark red
       tr
         td(colspan='2')
         p test

  script.
    function red() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function blue() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

What I want is for the popping selection of **light red** and **dark red** to span over two columns like the last **test** entry in the table.
I got the same example as html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <table align="center" 8px="" cellpadding="10" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="tab" value="red" onclick="red();">Red
        </th>
      <th>
        <input type="radio" name="tab" value="blue" onclick="blue();">Blue
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td id="color" colspan="2" class="hide">
          <input type="radio" value="light" name="one">light red
          <input type="radio" value="dark" name="two">dark red
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <p>test</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    function red() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function blue() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just need to change the javascript code as

```
document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'table-cell'
```

this will make the `<td>` display as table cell instead of,

```
document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'block';
```

which tries to display `<td>` as any other HTML tag 
this fixed your issue.

as another answer suggests to use `table-row` it would work accurately if you were using the `<tr>` to show/hide, in this case you are using `<td>` which is a cell thus the `table-cell` property is appropriate.

tags related to `<table>` have different display properties, you can get inform about display properties from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```js
function red() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'table-cell';
}

function blue() {
  document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" 8px="" cellpadding="10" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="tab" value="red" onclick="red();">Red
    </th>
    <th>
      <input type="radio" name="tab" value="blue" onclick="blue();">Blue
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="color" class="hide">
      <span><input type="radio" value="light" name="one">light red</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="dark" name="two">dark red</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <p>test</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @WildFly I have updated the answer with more explanation, you will get a better idea about display properties.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112113

> Normally a tr has display: table-row;. Obviously, the layout doesn't
>   stay the same if you make it display: block;. (If it "works" in IE, IE
>   is wrong.)
>
> Marking invalid.

So, normally it has table-row and if you change it will be block. which makes table uncontrollable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
    <table align="center" 8px="" cellpadding="10" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input type="radio" name="tab" value="red" onclick="red();">Red
        </th>
      <th>
        <input type="radio" name="tab" value="blue" onclick="blue();">Blue
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td id="color" colspan="2" class="hide">
          <input type="radio" value="light" name="one">light red
          <input type="radio" value="dark" name="two">dark red
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <p>test</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    function red() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'table-row';
    }
    function blue() {
      document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</html>
```